# Will parallel execution on selenium grid affect the execution time

Tags: java, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I'm writing automated scripts to load thousands of records into the web application and the time frame in which data has to be loaded is very less. So I thought of using Selenium Grid to run the scripts in parallel to achieve lesser time. Now, My question is will this affect the execution time of the automated scripts or the hub machine. There will be around 20 machines or maybe even more connected to the hub.

Also, Is using selenium grid the best option for this or I could use some other approach as well. And, feeding data from database or using web services is not possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> will this affect the execution time of the automated scripts or the hub machine

Maybe. It depends on the rest of your stack. Is the underlying server multi-threaded; will each Selenium Grid instance be provisioned its own process on the server? What about your database - will transaction locking block the other processes? Will any of your servers hit some performance bottleneck? Is the database [ACID compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID)? - I.e. Will running multiple Selenium instances like this cause race condition errors?

There's only one way to know for sure: Do a trial run, and benchmark it.

> Is using selenium grid the best option for this or I could use some other approach as well

If you have direct access to the database, then you could seed the data directly (using SQL, presumably). This would be *much* faster, if it's a viable option.

Also, it depends what you're typing to achieve here. Are you simply seeding the application with a tonne of data? (In which case, SQL is a better option.) Or, are you actually performance-testing the website? (In which case, intense parallel execution may be part of the specs.)

Comment: yeah I agree that seeding data directly into the database is the best option but the issue is this application is developed by a vendor. So there are only two options, do it manually or use the automation script. No option for using SQL and web services.

Comment: Is there any possibility of having `API` functionality added? (Or is it already available?) Again this would be much faster, if that's a possibility.

Comment: You could also consider sending `HTTP POST` requests directly, without actually clicking around the front-end... If that's a sensible option. (It depends how complex these `HTTP` requests are.) This won't be as fast as using an `API`, but you may at least save some time in re-loading multiple web pages.

Comment: Or, maybe if you disable JavaScript then performance will shoot up - if the website makes heavy use of unnecessary `AJAX` calls.

Comment: I think there's really no silver bullet to your problem -- you'll have you make an informed decision based on the complexity of the data inserting, and where the performance bottleneck(s) are.

Comment: As I've prepared scripts for few product types, It will take 10 minutes for each script to run. So I've to run the script for 500 records on one system and another 500 on another system.